# Error: Failed to lock directory "P:\Documents\R\win-library\3.6" for modifying try removing 'P:\Documents\R\win-library\3.6/00LOCK

Tags: r, package

I was trying to install the dplyr package on to my system but I am encountering the problem mentioned below:

`install.packages("dplyr")`

I got the error message

> Error: Failed to lock directory "P:\Documents\R\win-library\3.6" for modifying try removing 'P:\Documents\R\win-library\3.6/00LOCK

I tried to follow the instruction by removing the 00LOCK file that was automatically created but that doesnt help as even after retrying to install the package after deleting the file I faced the same problem wherein the 00LOCK folder got automatically generated. Can some one please help me out in understanding why am I facing this issue and how to correct this error and download the packages.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with this [pacman function](https://rdrr.io/cran/pacman/man/p_unlock.html) that attempts to delete a 00LOCK(s) if it exists:

```
install.packages('pacman')
pacman::p_unlock()
```

It worked for me! Hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried `view(installed.packages())` to see where the packages are stored, post that I specified the path `.libPath`("path I saw in the installed.packages()") and then tried to rerun the installation and it worked.